# How do I perform a SplitOn using Dapper's QuerySingle or QueryFirst methods?

Tags: c#, dapper

The most recent version of Dapper now includes query functions called `QuerySingle` and `QueryFirst` but these do not appear to support providing a `SplitOn` and Map value.

Is there some fundamental issue for why this appears to not be available? Is my only option to use `QueryAsync().FirstOrDefault()` ?

Comment: Do you get some error or is it documented somewhere ? Also can you please update your usage of the APIs `QuerySingle` and `QueryFirst` for a better idea

Comment: Looking at Dapper's source code, only Query<T1, T2, etc> supports splitOn.https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net/blob/master/Dapper/SqlMapper.cs

Comment: https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net/issues/595